# How to test with cookied user?

Tags: jmeter

I want to test the site with 2 types of users. 
First time user
Returning user

I am not sure how to test the returning user. Should I use cookie manager for this and use HTTP request twice with the same request to make the user cookied user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more related to `CACHE` than `COOKIE` to define your scenario.

1. `First Users`: Download All Resources and Save Them Locally.
2. `Returning Users`: Use the Downloaded Resources instead of downloading them from the server again.

Here, Resources are referred to static web elements like `images, .js, .css` files which won't change much.

To implement both users, use [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager). Use the default settings. Mark iterations in `Thread Group -> Loop Count` more than 1. Here, in first iteration, you are simulating First User. Remaining iterations are treated as `Returning Users` as JMeter uses Cache.

Note: If you check the option `Clear cache each iteration`, you are simulating all iterations as `First Comers/Users` as they always request/download resources from the server.

Comment: i have used something similar to your solution. But I used the http request twice instead of loop count more than 1. Can you check the screenshot and let me know if that could work.

Comment: One thread group is sufficient with single request. No need of two thread groups and two requests. In fact, that is wrong design. Keep one thread group & one http request and add Http Cache Manager to the Thread Group. Then, keep loop count more than 1 as suggested in the answer. Your screenshot does Not simulate what u asked for. Please go through cache management to understand Your scenario that defines first user & returning user.

Comment: Thanks, I will update the test. Just one more question. This solution you have suggested would work for any number of threads/users right?